# stop cplex in the middle of optimization since it is taking forever

Tags: cplex

I am new to CPLEX. 
While doing an optimization using CPLEX, it's taking forever so I want to stop the simulation there, how is that done?
Also, is it possible to make the simulation take less time?

Comment: Which API are you using (e.g., C, Java, Python, etc.)?

Comment: Also, what sort of problem are you solving; are all the variables continuous-valued or must some of them take integer values, how big is your problem, how long is 'forever'? Also it's not 'simulation' but a search process.